# Double ON in mssql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join

I have some queries written by mssql syntax, which have similar construction:

```
SELECT 
   [some columns]
   FROM Table1 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table2
          INNER JOIN Table3 ON [some conditions]
          INNER JOIN Table4 ON [some conditions]
          INNER JOIN Table5 ON [some conditions]
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON [some conditions]
     ON [some conditions]

     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON [some conditions]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table7 ON [some conditions]
   WHERE [some conditions]
   ORDER BY Numsv
```

I need to rewrite this query to the oracle SQL standard (pretty old standard):

```
SELECT 
   [some columns]
   FROM Table1 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
     ( 
          Table2
          INNER JOIN Table3 ON [some conditions]
          INNER JOIN Table4 ON [some conditions]
          INNER JOIN Table5 ON [some conditions]
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON [some conditions]
     ) 
     ON [some conditions]

     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON [some conditions]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table7 ON [some conditions]
   WHERE [some conditions]
   ORDER BY Numsv
```

Do I understand correctly that these are nested joins in the MSSQL query?
Double ON only might be when we use nested joins?

Comment: There's no need for rewriting, every DBMS supports both variations.

Comment: @dnoeth I have another db core, but its standard similar to oracle. If I put mssql nested joins, I'll get an exception. It can't process nested joins without parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  The syntax you have in SQL Server is standard syntax.  Not at all recommended, but allowed.

And Oracle supports nested joins as well.  [So this works in Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf2c1fa19e3cf035ec70da9307361599):

```
with t as (select 1 as x from dual)
select t.*
from t join
     t t2 join
     t t3
     on t3.x = t2.x
     on t2.x = t.x;
```

Both databases also allow you to use parentheses to order the `join`s in the `from` clause.  So the above is interpreted as:

```
with t as (select 1 as x from dual)
select t.*
from t join
     (t t2 join
      t t3
      on t3.x = t2.x
     )
     on t2.x = t.x;
```

There are some very rare circumstances where I use parentheses in the `FROM` clause, apart from answering questions about MS Access which requires them.  But those are highly specific and unusual.

Comment: I have another DB core. If I told you that name, you won't recognize it. This is the "linter", Russian product. Its syntax very similar to oracle, but not always.